# ORA-00979: Not a GROUP BY Expression - Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Am a datastage developer and while migrating jobs from an older version of datastage to a new version. Am facing an issue with the below mentioned query.

```
SELECT   1
FROM     DUAL
GROUP BY CUBE (1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

The SQL retuns 64 rows with 1 as value in my PROD server (Oracle 10) and is giving me the below error in the DEV (Oracle 12c) . there are no other differences between the tables.

`ORA-00979: Not a GROUP BY Expression`

Thanks
Vivekan s

Comment: it seems oracle 12c interprets all those 1s in the CUBE expression as different from the 1 in SELECT.This also works on 11g.Just find a different way to generate 64 rows of 1.

Comment: Thanks Mihai - I tried to generate 64 rows using the below mentioned SQL and even that doesnt seem to give me any rows 

select 1 from Dual 
start with rownum = 1 
connect by rownum < 65

Comment: Would `WITH T AS (
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
FROM T
CROSS JOIN T
CROSS JOIN T
CROSS JOIN T
CROSS JOIN T
CROSS JOIN T
;` possibly work for you? (Works on 11g…)

Comment: Another option 
`SELECT 1 col
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 64`

Comment: May you should open a SR with Oracle. This might be considered as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
select rpad('1',63, '1') from dual;
```

generates a string of 1's.  rpad(starting char, repeat count, fill char)